# How to flatten Tree in Scala?

Tags: scala, tree, functional-programming

It is pretty easy to write `flatten(lol: List[List[T]]): List[T]` which transforms a list of lists to a new list. Other "flat" collections (e.g. `Set`) seem to provide `flatten` too.

Now I wonder if I can define a `flatten` for `Tree[T]`(defined as a `T` and list of `Tree[T]`s).

Comment: Please add full type name for `Tree` (there is no `Tree` in standard library) and examples of input data and result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to define that flatten exactly, but you can look at the Scalaz Tree implementation:
https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Tree.scala

If you want flatten to return you list of all Tree nodes, then Scalaz already provides you what you want:

```
def flatten: Stream[A]
```

Result type is Stream instead of List, but this is not a problem I guess.
If you want something more sophisticated, then you can probably implement it using existing `flatMap`:

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => Tree[B]): Tree[B]
```

Let's say you have `Tree` of type `Tree[Tree[A]]` and want to flatten it to `Tree[A]`:

```
def flatten1: Tree[A] = flatMap(identity)
```

This will work also for other, more weird scenarios. For example, you can have `Tree[List[A]]`, and want to flatten everything inside that `Lists` without affecting Tree structure itself:

```
def flatten2[B]: Tree[List[B]] = flatMap(l => leaf(l.flatten))
```

Looks like it works as expected:

```
scala> node(List(List(1)), Stream(node(List(List(2)), Stream(leaf(List(List(3, 4), List(5))))), leaf(List(List(4)))))
res20: scalaz.Tree[List[List[Int]]] = <tree>

scala> res20.flatMap(l => leaf(l.flatten)).drawTree
res23: String = 
"List(1)
|
+- List(2)
|  |
|  `- List(3, 4, 5)
|
`- List(4)
"
```

It could be worth noting that scalaz Tree is also a Monad. If you will look at the scalaz/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/TreeTest.scala you will see which laws are fulfilled for Tree:

```
checkAll("Tree", equal.laws[Tree[Int]])
checkAll("Tree", traverse1.laws[Tree])
checkAll("Tree", applicative.laws[Tree])
checkAll("Tree", comonad.laws[Tree])
```

I don't know why monad is not here, but if you will add `checkAll("Tree", monad.laws[Tree])` and run tests again, they will pass.

Comment: Thank you! `def flatMap[B](f: A => Tree[B]): Tree[B]` is probably what I need. Does it comply to monadic laws ? or in other worda, is the `Tree` a monad ?

Comment: I'm glad that you found what you need! I added one paragraph about laws which apply to Tree, but in short yes, scalaz Tree is a monad. If that is what you were looking for please don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

This is not perfect, just serves an example. All you need to do is to traverse a tree in depth-first or breadth-first manner and collect results. Pretty much the same as `flatten` for lists.

1) Define a tree structure (I know, I know it's not the best way to do it :)):

```
scala> case class Node[T](value: T, left: Option[Node[T]] = None,
     |  right: Option[Node[T]] = None)
defined class Node
```

2) Create a little tree:

```
scala> val tree = Node(13,
     |   Some(Node(8,
     |     Some(Node(1)), Some(Node(11)))), 
     |   Some(Node(17,
     |     Some(Node(15)), Some(Node(25))))
     | )
tree: Node[Int] = Node(13,Some(Node(8,Some(Node(1,None,None)),Some(Node(11,None,None)))),Some(Node(17,Some(Node(15,None,None)),Some(Node(25,None,None)))))
```

3) Implement a function that can traverse a tree:

```
scala> def observe[T](node: Node[T], f: Node[T] => Unit): Unit = {
     |   f(node)
     |   node.left foreach { observe(_, f) }
     |   node.right foreach { observe(_, f) }
     | }
observe: [T](node: Node[T], f: Node[T] => Unit)Unit
```

4) Use it to define a function that prints all values:

```
scala> def printall = observe(tree, (n: Node[_]) => println(n.value))
printall: Unit
```

5) Finally, define that `flatten` function:

```
scala> def flatten[T](node: Node[T]): List[T] = {
     |   def flatten[T](node: Option[Node[T]]): List[T] =
     |     node match {
     |       case Some(n) =>
     |         n.value :: flatten(n.left) ::: flatten(n.right)
     |       case None => Nil
     |     }
     |  
     |  flatten(Some(node))
     | }
flatten: [T](node: Node[T])List[T]
```

6) Let's test. First print all elems:

```
scala> printall
13
8
1
11
17
15
25
```

7) Run `flatten`:

```
scala> flatten(tree)
res1: List[Int] = List(13, 8, 1, 11, 17, 15, 25)
```

It's a sort of general purpose tree algorithm like tree traversal. I made it return `T`s instead of `Node`s, change it as you like.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to define Tree like so:

```
case class Tree[T]( value:T, kids:List[Tree[T]] )
```

First, I wouldn't want to use `:::` in the solution because of the performance implications.  Second, I'd want to do something much more general -- define a fold operator for the type, which can be used for all sorts of things -- and then simply use a fold to define `flatten`:

```
case class Tree[T]( value:T, kids:List[Tree[T]] ) {
  def /:[A]( init:A )( f: (A,T) => A ):A =
    ( f(init,value) /: kids )( (soFar,kid) => ( soFar /: kid )(f) )
  def flatten =
    ( List.empty[T] /: this )( (soFar,value) => value::soFar ).reverse
}
```

Here's a test:

```
scala> val t = Tree( 1, List( Tree( 2, List( Tree(3,Nil), Tree(4,Nil) ) ), Tree(5,Nil), Tree( 6, List( Tree(7,Nil) ) ) ) )
t: Tree[Int] = Tree(1,List(Tree(2,List(Tree(3,List()), Tree(4,List()))), Tree(5,List()), Tree(6,List(Tree(7,List())))))

scala> t.flatten
res15: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```